# Spine.js change event not firing

Tags: jquery, html, spine.js

I have something like this:

```
events: {
    "change .name": "dosomething"
},

dosomething: function() {
    console.log("Hi.");
}
```

and in my HTML:

```
<input class="name" type="text"></input>
```

But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think it would be like this `events: { '.name' :{ "change" : "dosomething"},}`

Comment: Your problem may have many causes, the most likely being that you haven't instantiated the controller.